# Does Diagnostics.TraceSource support buffered logging?

Tags: .net, logging, system.diagnostics, tracesource

Does Diagnostics.TraceSource support buffered logging or some other queuing mechanism?

I've no doubt come across the plethora of questions on the various logging frameworks.  On many of those questions someone chimes in that "I wish people would just use TraceSource it does everything log4net and NLog does".   But in my travels and googles I haven't found any discussion on buffered or batch logging, like that supported in NLog and Log4Net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By itself, no. But there is nothing stopping you from implementing a `TraceListener` that does it. The model appears to be open enough to latch on pretty much any logging requirements you need to. Just be sure to to make your `TraceListener` at least as thread safe as `TraceSource` itself.

Comment: That was my conclusion, but I haven't used trace source too much.  Thanks.